# Which one is correct will or is?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, usage, word-difference, verb-usage

> He will more likely to enter a competition
>
> He is more likely to enter a competition

Which one is correct?

Comment: "Will" is commonly used with another verb when talking about the *future*, so your first sentence is not grammatical.  Both "is" or "will be" can be correct.  Could you please edit your question to add more information on what you want to say?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is correct grammatically, whereas the first sentence isn't correct.

In addition to the usage of likely as an adjective, the following sentences
can be formed:

He'll be more likely to enter a competition.

It's more likely that he'll enter a competition.

If you want to use it as an adverb, the sentence should be as follows:

He will more likely enter a competition.